# Testing apps on a Firefox OS Phone Device

Tags: firefox, operating-system, firefox-os

I have the Keon from geeksphone. The Mozilla developer site talks about using the emulator, but nothing about installing an application onto a physical device. It is a developer phone, so I assume there's a way to develop with it? I can host the app and test it in the phone's browser, but I'd prefer trying to package it up and actually install it onto the device.

Found it. Now I need to figure out how to install an XPI file...

[Testing Packaged Apps](https://marketplace.firefox.com/developers/docs/packaged)

[Android bridge API](https://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up)

Answer (score 0):

> Now I need to figure out how to install an XPI file...

`XPI` files are add-ons, which FirefoxOS does not support at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You want to install FirefoxOS Simulator addon file which is in `.xpi format`? If yes then just drag and drop the file onto Firefox Browser, it will get installed.